# Difference of defining an array inside and outside a for loop

Tags: javascript

the title is already clear, what's the difference between die create an array inside or outside a for loop.

I will give you an example.

```
 var studentsarray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

        var students = {
                id:i,
                roll:"9",
                age:13
        }//end students

        studentsarray.push(students);

        localStorage.setItem('veritabani', JSON.stringify(studentsarray));

    }//end for

    var aldim = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('veritabani'));

    $.each(aldim, function(i,item){
        alert(item.id);
    });
```

if i define inside a for loop, i can't reach all elements, but if i define outside the for loop, it is only the last value of(id) displayed.

Can you explain why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read up on the concept of [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 0):

Few observations:

1. Javascript only has function level scoping, so defining a variable inside the for loop is equivalent to defining it outside.
2. However, the variable assignment will happen multiple times if inside the for loop
3. Please note JSON.stringify is setting studentarray by value multiple times, did you really mean to do this inside the for loop?
4. I wonder if this is really what you meant to do?

   ```
   var studentsarray = [];

   for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
      studentsarray.push({id: i, roll:"9", age:13 });
   }

   localStorage.setItem('veritabani', JSON.stringify(studentsarray));

   var aldim = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('veritabani'));
   $.each(aldim, function(i,item){
       alert(item.id);
   });
   ```